# Script triggered onEdit runs into permissions error when trying to edit protected sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have a problem with a Google script for a spreadsheet. I have a script installed **onEdit** through the Resources menu. The script copies some cells from an **unprotected** sheet to a **protected** sheet. The script works fine when I'm logged in to my account (I'm the owner of the spreadsheet), but runs into permission errors when run from a collaborator's account who has no access to the protected sheet. ***Shouldn't the script run as me (the account owner) and not run into permission issues?***
Another script in the same spreadsheet that runs **onFormSubmit** is able to edit a **protected** sheet when a collaborator submits a form, even though he has no access to the protected sheet.  This suggests the problem is not with permissions per se, but that the problem is specific to the onEdit trigger, right?

Comment: Maybe adding the relevant bits of code would help

Comment: I am running into a similar issue. I've installed `triggeredOnEdit` as an onEdit trigger running as me (the owner). When I use the spreadsheet, everything works. When I try it with another account, I run into a permission error when I try to edit a protected sheet.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. The onEdit trigger is one of three 'simple triggers'.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers):
"These simple triggers run in response to actions in Google Spreadsheets, and they run as the active user. For example, if Bob opens the Spreadsheet, then the onOpen function runs as Bob, irrespective of who added the script to the Spreadsheet.  For this reason, the simple triggers are restricted in what they are permitted to do:

- They cannot execute when the Spreadsheet is opened in read-only mode.
- They cannot determine the current user.
- They cannot access any services that require authentication as that
  user. For example, the Google Translate service is anonymous and can
  be accessed by the simple triggers. Google Calendar, Gmail, and Sites
  are not anonymous and the simple triggers cannot access those
  services.
- They can only modify the current Spreadsheet. Access to other
  Spreadsheets is forbidden.

Comment: onEdit can be a simple trigger, but it can also be a Container-specific triggered that should "execute under the identity of the user who created the trigger" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_container_triggers) and "The onEdit function can write to any cell on a spreadsheet."  As far as I can tell, if the script is set up from the Script Editor > Resources > Current script's triggers > Run > Events > From Spreadsheet > On edit (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#ActionTriggers) it should behave as a container-specific installable trigger.

Comment: Oh I see.. sorry, I misunderstood your question. Do you have both the onEdit and the onFormSubmit triggers only installed for the owner? If you have the onEdit trigger installed for the collaborator, but not for the owner, it will run as the collaborator and thus not have access to the protected sheet.

Comment: They are both installed for the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use installed trigger for it to work