# Convert all the sheets to pdf every 8 hour or by changing a cell value with Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, pdf-generation

I just started writing script and I'm trying to convert a Google spreadsheet (multiple sheets) to a PDF file by changing cell value (example A1, i try but i didn't obtain nothing) or each 8 hr. The script below works, but it only creates a PDF when i run the script. I've trying to add a project's trigger: time-based each 8 hr but i received an email: Bad value (line 4, file "Code") so in the folder there were no new pdf files.

```
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {

// If a sheet ID was provided, open that sheet, otherwise assume script is
// sheet-bound, and open the active spreadsheet.
var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get folder containing spreadsheet, for later export
var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
if (parents.hasNext()) {
var folder = parents.next();
}
else {
folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
}

//additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

  // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if 
optSheetId is provided
  + (optSheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()) : ('&id=' + ss.getId()))

  // following parameters are optional...
  + '&size=letter'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional 
headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each 
page

var options = {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
 }
}
var date = Utilities.formatDate8new Date(). "GMT+2" ""hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy")
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/" + 
url_ext, options);
var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + date + '.pdf');

//from here you should be able to use and manipulate the blob to send and 
email or create a file per usual.
//In this example, I save the pdf to drive
folder.createFile(blob);

}
```

When i tried to run the script automatically changing the cell value i wrote another script reported below (don't work):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var langName = 'Sheet1'
var langCell = 'A1'

var curSheet = e.range.getSheet()

if (curSheet.getName() === langName) {
if (e.range.getA1Notation() === langCell) {
  savePDFs()      
 }
}
```

Comment: Authorization issue - simplec triggers have none

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script triggered onEdit runs into permissions error when trying to edit protected sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732976/script-triggered-onedit-runs-into-permissions-error-when-trying-to-edit-protecte)